# Rails 5 default_url_options oddities

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a pretty simple rails app that I'm working on upgrading from Rails 4 to Rails 5, but I'm noticing some weirdness with `default_url_options`

In `config/environments/test.rb` I have:

```
Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host]= ENV["HTTP_HOST"] || "localhost"
Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:port]= ENV["PORT"] || 3000
```

My application has a namespace called `api`. In my request specs, I'm seeing this:

```
[1] pry> api_v3_sample_url
=> "http://www.example.com:3000/api/v3/sample"
[2] pry> Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.api_v3_sample_url
=> "http://localhost:3000/api/v3/sample"
```

What am I missing that is causing those URLs to be different?

**EDIT**

Per [this thread](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/1275#issuecomment-69807351) I set

```
config.action_controller.default_url_options = {
  host: ENV['HTTP_HOST'] || 'localhost'
}
```

in `config/environments/test.rb` but now I get this:

```
> Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.api_v3_sample_url
ArgumentError: Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true
> api_v3_sample_url
=> "http://www.example.com/api/v3/sample"
```

**EDIT 2**

Probably worth noting that these are request specs and not feature specs (not using capybara).

Answer (score 3):

This should fix the issue in controller/request specs:

```
config.action_controller.default_url_options = {
  host: ENV['HTTP_HOST'] || 'localhost'
}
```

As for why this is occurring, there's some [more information available in this ongoing thread on Github](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/1275#issuecomment-69807351]).

Comment: @Eugene You didn't need to remove the code you had.

Comment: @coreward even with the original code back, the behavior is the same as it was originally

Comment: @Eugene Hmm, bummer, but makes sense per your clarifications/edits.